# How do I force Postgres to respect the configuration file on service start? Or how can I assign shared_buffer and max_connections on boot?

Tags: postgresql

When I attempt to start my server, this is the error:

```
2023-02-28 03:27:57.896 UTC [64390] FATAL:  could not map anonymous shared memory: Cannot allocate memory
2023-02-28 03:27:57.896 UTC [64390] HINT:  This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request for a shared memory segment exceeded available memory, swap space, or huge pages. To reduce the request size (currently 17214251008 bytes), reduce PostgreSQL's shared memory usage, perhaps by reducing shared_buffers or max_connections.
2023-02-28 03:27:57.896 UTC [64390] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

My /etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf file originally contained:

```
shared_buffer = 2048MB
max_connections = 500
```

I've tried the following settings:

```
shared_buffer=128kB
max_connections = 5
```

and a number of settings between, none of which changed the error by even a single byte.

So how do I force postgresql to use the values it says it was using from the postgresql.conf files?  Is there a way to allow me to set the server variables on boot?

Comment: You can start the server with `strace --single /path/to/postgres -D /etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf postgres` to trace the system calls and identify which one caused the error. There is some operating system configuration that unduly restricts the amount of shared memory the PostgreSQL process can allocate. You have to find which one.

Comment: Is that the correct config file for the server you are starting?  (Easy way to tell: introduce an intentional syntax error into the file. If the error message doesn't change, then that isn't the file being used) Did you remove the leading '#' from the lines?  Are there more lines further down (or in postgresql.auto.conf) changing your settings back to the old ones?

Comment: It was using some internal postgresql.auto.conf file it had safely tucked in its data folder - good debug tips, made it easy to find, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

So it was correctly reading the postgresql.conf file, but it had such insane system settings that it was using 2gb per shared_buffer block, with thousands of blocks.

What I ended up doing was very dangerous, but I went into the postgres data folder, edited the postgresql.auto.conf launching file, found the line that said shared_buffer=2048576, and changed that down to 128.  Boot successful!